# How durable is a silanized surface?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, surface-chemistry

I have two questions regarding silanization:

1) How durable is a silanized glass surface? (i.e. **How long** a silanized surface can be kept without any change in its wettability or contact angle?)

2) What are the optimum conditions for keeping a silanized surface while it's idle and dry? (e.g. maintenance temperature, **humidity**, etc. Should it be kept in a desiccator or not necessarily?)

Comment: Try looking up rainx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If done properly, reactions with silanes or siloxanes are effectively permanent, unless removed by *serious* mechanical abrasion (e.g., scraping the material below the coating) or some sort of etching underneath.

The [silanization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silanization) process involves creating new covalent $\ce{Si-O}$ bonds, which are quite strong.

1. The silane surface itself should be durable. However, the contact angle may change as material adsorbs on top of it. For example, a colleague has shown that [hydrocarbon contaminants change the wettability of many surfaces](http://doi.org/0.1038/nmat3709)
2. I don't think any particular storage is necessary. We store in a vacuum desiccator to minimize the effect of contamination, but as long as you clean the surface, the properties should be consistent.

Comment: ​Therefore, I can keep my silanized glass spheres in a closed-cap bottle for a long enough time and probably wash them before I need to use. BTW, I know that with silanization by Octadeyltrichlorosilane, I can reach to CA~110 deg for glass. Do you know what is the Maximum contact angle people could reach on glass, and with what solution? Thanks